# Why is python 3.6.1. not available in pyenv?

Tags: python, repository, release, pyenv

According to [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/), `Python 3.6.1` was released at the end of March. But:

```
» pyenv install -l | grep 3\.6\.
  3.6.0a1
  3.6.0a3
  3.6-dev
```

1. Why is `Python 3.6.1` not yet available in `pyenv`?
2. Where can I find documentation about the releases that `pyenv` supports? (when it was added, what is in progress, ...). The [pyenv documentation](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) does not give this information.
3. Is there a repository for Python releases supported by `pyenv`? (similar to `PyPi`)

Comment: Did you try `pyenv update`?

Comment: @amigcamel omg! That did the trick, now I have 3.6.0 and 3.6.1. That `update` command does not even appear en `pyenv --help`, and there is no `man pyenv`. I do not find it in pyenv documentation. Where did you find this?

Comment: It's mentioned in [pyenv-installer](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer). See the answer below.

Comment: Same problem with python 3.7.1. I tried `brew upgrade pyenv` but I get: `Error: pyenv 1.2.7 already installed`

Answer (score 126, accepted):

### If you installed pyenv via [pyenv installer](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer):

```
pyenv update
```

### If you installed pyenv via Homebrew

```
brew upgrade pyenv
```

### If you installed pyenv via Git:

```
cd $(pyenv root) && git pull
```

Answer (score 11):

I tried `pyenv update` but that did not resolve the issue for me.

I had to `brew update && brew upgrade pyenv` before doing `pyenv install 3.6.1`

Answer (score 0):

Thx @amigcamel for the full answer. I installed via Git so I didn't have `pyenv update` but I didn't want to remember the Git method so I made this with the help of Copilot and put it in my profile.  So now I have `pyenv update`.

```
pyenv() {
    local pyenv_bin="/home/aquar/.pyenv/bin/pyenv"
    local first_arg="$1"

    # Check if the first argument is "update"
    if [ "$first_arg" = "update" ]; then
        # Execute the update commands
        pushd "$(pyenv root)" && git pull && popd
    else
        # Pass all arguments to the original pyenv binary
        "$pyenv_bin" "$@"
    fi
}
```