# How to use pipenv to create a virtual environment with a specific python version?

Tags: python, pipenv

I have made a project folder here: Desktop/xetra_project

I installed python 3.11 and would like to use pipenv to create a virtual environment with python 3.11 for this project.

When I try to create a virtual environment with python 3.11 in this project folder, I end up outside of this project folder and within other virtual environments. As a result, I am left with python 3.10.6. Is there someone who may know what I am doing wrong? Here are my terminal commands and responses:

➜  xetra_project pipenv shell --python /usr/local/bin/python3.11

Launching subshell in virtual environment...
. /Users/hanna/.venv/bin/activate
/Users/hanna/.zshrc:208: command not found: libpq
/Users/hanna/.zshrc:unset:222: LDFLAGS=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib: invalid parameter name
(base) ➜  ~  . /Users/hanna/.venv/bin/activate

(.venv) (base) ➜  ~ python -V

Python 3.10.6

I have a lot of python versions installed on my computer. See attached picture.

[image: so many pythons]

Comment: Do you have multiple Python versions installed? If so, please explain in your post.

Comment: You could try `py -3.11 -m venv venv`

Comment: @BentheCoder Yes, I just added a picture of all the Python versions I have installed

Comment: if you are open to create env with `venv` you can refer [virtual env with venv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75129920/how-to-config-python-virtual-environment-with-a-specific-python-version/75130194#75130194). so `cd /usr/local/bin/python3.11` and then `python3.11 -m venv venv`

Comment: one debug you can do, once you activate the env, if you type `which python`, then python should be picked from the virtual env which was created.

Comment: "which python" returns /usr/local/bin/python and "which python3" returns /opt/homebrew/bin/python3.
How can I use this information to solve the problem?