# pyenv install -l does not show the version I need to install

Tags: pyenv

For a project I need Python version 3.6.8 and I used `pyenv install -l`
 to list all the version available to install but could not find it.
After I tried several times including: use `brew upgrade pyenv`,  tried uninstall  pyenv,  tried `brew update` `brew upgrade` and then update pyenv, still no luck to find the version I need.
Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Comment: Answer by OP below, `pyenv update` worked for me (2024)

Answer (score 2):

After many searches, found answer here:
[Why is python 3.6.1. not available in pyenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993714/why-is-python-3-6-1-not-available-in-pyenv)
`pyenv update` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried multiple things after going from one SO page to another. The only thing that worked for me was upgrading `pyenv`. However, `pyenv update` did not resolve the issue as I installed `pyenv` on my Mac via Homebrew, so I had to upgrade it via `brew`:

```
brew upgrade pyenv
```

So I think the answer is: you have to upgrade `pyenv` but, how you have to upgrade it depends on how you installed it.

If you installed it via https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer then yes - `pyenv update` is going to work for you

Answer (score 1):

> See all available versions with `pyenv install --list'.
>
> If the version you need is missing, try upgrading pyenv:

`cd ~/.pyenv/plugins/python-build/../.. && git pull && cd -`