# pyenv wont find python version 3.8.7 to install

Tags: python, macos, pyenv

I am trying to install python version 3.8.7. According to the python documentation (https://docs.python.org/3.8/), this is the most up to date version of 3.8.

but if I run
`pyenv install --list`
I cannot see version 3.8.7 in the list of available downloads.

Does anyone know why this is or failing that, how I can upgrade to version 3.8.7 on Mac?

Comment: Upgrade your pyenv version to 1.2.22.

Comment: Thanks for this, I installed using brew so I assumed it would have installed the most up to date version. I used {brew update pyenv} and it updated to 1.2.22, I can now see the version I want

Comment: This answer helped me solve this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43996315/2327761 By using `brew upgrade pyenv` I updated pyenv to version 1.2.22 and then I could see python version 3.8.7