# Why doesn't 'pyenv install --list' list all miniconda distributions I see on https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/?

Tags: python-3.x, miniconda, pyenv

```
pyenv install --list | grep miniconda
```

Why does this not return miniconda packages that include the corresponding python versions (eg py38 in Miniconda3-py38_4.9.2-MacOSX-x86_64.sh)

I only get the old versions + miniconda3-latest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is python 3.6.1. not available in pyenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993714/why-is-python-3-6-1-not-available-in-pyenv)

Comment: answer from github: "someone has to update the list of available versions, which doesnt happen often because people dont use miniconda with pyenv a whole lot"